# Print Multiple Results from a Database

Tags: php, sql, database

Currently I have an sql query which finds the amount of records in the database for a specific person (Ms White), how can I repeat the function for every surname within the table and print them out in a sensible format?

```
  $query = "SELECT COUNT(Surname) FROM Customers WHERE Surname='White'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better to run just one query with the `count` per each surname?

```
select Surname, count(*) as Total from Customers
group by Surname
```

This will return results like this:

```
Person  Total
White       4
Mustard     2
Plum        1
etc...
```

Answer (score 5):

GROUP BY I think is what you are looking for

```
SELECT COUNT(*),Surname FROM Customers GROUP BY Surname
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly, however how do I print these in a logical way? Currently all I get is a series of numbers(depending on how many orders each person has made)?

Comment: Well are you printing the second column (the Surname one)? YOu can also sort the results (using ORDER BY) by Surname or the COUNT

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT count(1) as "Counter", surname FROM Customers GROUP BY surname
```

This will give you output like below.

```
Counter  +  Surname
++++++++++++++++++++
  10     +  SN1
  15     +  SN2
  11     +  SN3
```